# How to get all the elements out of ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, hashmap

I have an ArrayList HashMap that holds Contacts -names and phone numbers-. I would like to check and make sure that these items are in the ArrayList HashMap before I send it to the SQL database for saving. All of the code below works, I just do not have a clue as of how to print all the contents in the ArrayList. The things I have tried have not worked and I do not know how to use Log...I am rather new to this.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class Contacts extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;

private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getContacts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

private static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

private static HashMap<String, String> contacts = new HashMap<String,String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

}

public void btnAddContacts_Click(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}

public void btnDone_Click(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(Contacts.this, Message.class);
    startActivity(i);
}



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (reqCode) {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();
                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id =
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    String hasPhone =
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id,
                                null, null);
                        phones.moveToFirst();
                        String phn_no = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        contacts.put(name, phn_no);


                        while (c.moveToNext()) {
                            String id1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

                            String name1 = contacts.get(id1);
                            String phone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));

                            HashMap<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            h.put("name", name1);
                            h.put("phone", phone);
                            data1.add(h);
                        }



                        Toast.makeText(this, "contact info : " + phn_no + "\n" + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            }
    }

}


}
```

the XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"     tools:context="akh.seniorproj.Contacts">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact"
    android:id="@+id/contact1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btnAddContacts_Click" />


<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact"
    android:id="@+id/contact2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contact1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btnAddContacts_Click" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact"
    android:id="@+id/contact3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contact2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btnAddContacts_Click" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact"
    android:id="@+id/contact4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/contact3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btnAddContacts_Click" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/Next1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="btnDone_Click" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As per your code, you should be getting everything right into `data1`. If you want to log just type `Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Message here");`

Comment: ...thank you for your comment but I don't know where to put this exactly. could you explain?? I put it at the end of the last while loop and it prints in the log but only prints "contacts: "message here"" each time before the toast runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can print all the values in `data1` using `data1.toString()`

Comment: @isabella put the data1.toString() in log  below your toast .. to see the result

Comment: ...okay... I put it in this log " Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), data1.toString());" but it only print out "Contacts﹕ []"

Comment: OKAY I fixed it. Thank you for your answer because it was the one that worked! It was my while loop that wasn't working

Answer (score 4):

```
for (HashMap<String, String> contact : data1) {
    for (Entry<String, String> item : contact.entrySet()) {
        String key = item.getKey();
        String value = item.getValue();
        ... do whatever you want to do to print things
    }
}
```

Comment: got an error "foreach not applicable to type 'java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>'"

Comment: my bad, fixed. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Sample program to achieve what you want .

```
public class mainClass {
 public static void main(String[] args){
 HashMap<String , String> map1 = new HashMap();
  map1.put("ONE", "1");
  map1.put("TWO", "2");
  map1.put("THREE", "3");
  map1.put("FOUR", "4");
  map1.put("FIVE", "5");

  HashMap<String , String> map2 = new HashMap();
  map2.put("ONE", "1");
  map2.put("TWO", "2");
  map2.put("THREE", "3");
  map2.put("FOUR", "4");
  map2.put("FIVE", "5");


 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getContacts = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 getContacts.add(map1);
 getContacts.add(map2);

 for(HashMap<String,String> map : getContacts ){
     // get your hashmap keys 
     Set <String>setOfKeys = map.keySet();

     Iterator<String> iterator = setOfKeys.iterator();

     while (iterator.hasNext()) {
         /**
          * next() method returns the next key from Iterator instance.
          * return type of next() method is Object so we need to do DownCasting to String
          */
         String key = (String) iterator.next();

         /**
          * once we know the 'key', we can get the value from the HashMap
          * by calling get() method
          */
          String value = (String)map.get(key);

         System.out.println("Key: "+ key+", Value: "+ value);
         // store the key + value to whatever you want here 
          }
 }


   }
  }
```

Comment: Why would you do that instead of using for-each loops?

Comment: nice catch , no particular reason , i guess both will work just as good here .

Comment: thank you for the reply. I used the last part of your code and nothing printed in the log so then I added "Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "Key: "+ key+", Value: "+ value);" and still nothing...do you mind explaining

Comment: Debug and see what the values are before using your log statements just to be sure .
try using system.out.println and check your logcat , may something is wrong with your log statement , use can also use toasts as well .

Answer (score 0):

try this code to print the values in your list check it in the log

```
for(int i=0;i< data1.size();i++){


    HashMap<String, String> h= data1.get(i);

       for (TypeKey name: h.keySet()){

            String key =name.toString();
            String value = h.get(name).toString();  
            System.out.println(key + " " + value);  


    } 
}
```

include this code before passing the data to your db.

Comment: thank you for your reply...but where exactly do I place this? I placed it after the last while loop before the toast and I get these errors "Cannot resolve symbol "TypeKey" " and "Cannot resolve method ".toString()"